# Sprite Sheet Issues?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, sprite-sheet

I created sprite sheets with Zwoptex and generated the .plist file. I am having issues linking these sprite sheets to my iOS game. I loaded the .plist and .png files created on Zwoptex to Xcode, but the changes are not being recognized. I don't know why this is happening. The game was created with cocos.

Thanks!

Comment: more info needed … what did you try? What result do you get and what are you expecting? Any warning/error messages?

Comment: I used Zwoptex to create sprite sheets and the .plist files. 

I manually added the .plist and the related .png files to the xcode project. All these files do show up on the Project Navigator, so I do see them. I proceeded to update the **AppDelegate.m** on the project using the following code:

Comment: `// Removes the startup flicker
 [self removeStartupFlicker];
    // Load the sprite files
    if ( [GameUtils sharedUtils].deviceType == kDeviceIPad ) {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Images.plist"];
        [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Images.png"];
        
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Images@2x~ipad.plist"];
        [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Images@2x~ipad.png"];`

Comment: The **@2x~ipad** files were the recently added to the xcode project. 

Once I save and I run my project, it doesn't recognize the newly added files.

I don't know what is going on. Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use a spriteSheet in cocos2d im not sure if this is what your looking for as to the lack of detail but

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"TreeSequance.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *treeSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"TreeSequance.png"];

           CCSprite *smallerTree = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Tree1.png"];

                smallerTree.position = ccp(500,500);
                [treeSheet addChild:smallerTree];
                [self addChild:treeSheet];
```

Comment: I used this `// Removes the startup flicker [self removeStartupFlicker]; // Load the sprite files if ( [GameUtils sharedUtils].deviceType == kDeviceIPad ) { [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Images.plist"]; [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Images.png"]; [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Images@2x~ipad.plist"]; [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Images@2x~ipad.png"];